# GeoServer integration with GeoWebCache. Empty miss reason

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I enabled the direct integration with GeoWebCache within GeoServer for a set of static maps. But currently all the requests are returning with the Header `geowebcache-cache-result: MISS` and the `geowebcache-miss-reason:` with and empty string.

I understand that for the request to be served with the cache it needs to fulfill all the requirements:

- WMS Direct integration is enabled (you can set this on the Caching defaults page)
- tiled=true is included in the request
- The request only references a single layer
- Caching is enabled for that layer
- The image requested is of the same height and width as the size saved in the layer configuration
- The requested CRS matches one of the available tile layer gridsets
- The image requested lines up with the existing grid bounds
- A parameter is included for which there is a corresponding Parameter Filter

The requests when sent trough the demo site in the GeoWebCache configuration return a `geowebcache-cache-result: HIT` so the cache is working. But its sending the requests directly to the GeoWebCache

The requests that I make trough the WMS integration have the following parameters

```
https://GEOSERVERHOST.com/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS
&VERSION=1.3.0
&REQUEST=GetMap
&FORMAT=image/png
&TRANSPARENT=true
&LAYERS=test:flood_riverbed
&TILED=true
&WIDTH=256
&HEIGHT=256
&CRS=EPSG:3857
&STYLES=
&BBOX=-215246.6716510579%2C4520180.104672182%2C-195678.7924100528%2C4539747.983913188
```

The Gridset available for the layers is the default EPSG:900913

I cannot find where the issue is, more with the "miss-reason" beeing empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you make sure the origins match? Any way wouldn't it be easier to use WMTS

Comment: Yes I would like to change to WMTS but in a future release as it requires a few changes with OpenLayers.
As for the origins, for what I check there is a specific miss message "request does not align to grid" for that. But I'll check if it can be the issue

Comment: Ok found the issue. It was because in the layer creation I set the "Bounding Boxes" to compute from data instead of the SRS bounds.