# GeoWebCache not caching blank tiles - configurable?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I am using GeoNode + GeoServer + GeoWebCache. I have a map with a number of layers that only apply to a certain section of the map, e.g. US states. However, no matter where on the map I navigate, only tiles with data for that layer are cached. This results in a pretty significant performance hit, since all the layers for the state(s) not in view are queried and presumably taking up processing power to generate blank tiles.

I have read the docs and other questions here and there's no specific mention of blank tiles and caching. ([This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363034/geoserver-integration-with-geowebcache-empty-miss-reason) is kinda related however I think the person asking was confusing GWC's server-side cache with client-side caching.)

Is this by design, or am I missing a configuration option? I understand this would likely result in the bulk of my cache being blank tiles, but that seems better than the performance hit? I don't think that configuring a layer filter would help in this case, at least it doesn't appear to.

Comment: can you add version numbers and operating system details to your question, please?